# CSS Float left to a Div centered on the page

Tags: html, css, css-float, margin, centering

I have a div in the middle of my page used as the container for everything from my content to the  menu, now my client wants to have an additional box the the side of this. I use this code to center the container:

```
#container {
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

and I want anouther div to the side lets say this:

```
    #sidecontainer {
        width:200px;
        float:left;
    }
```

stripped down version of the html:

```
<div id="container">stuff (Divs and other jazz)</div>
<div id="sidecontainer">stuff (Divs and other jazz)</div>
```

Now if i apply float left to the container it removes the margins that get it in the middle of the page. So how do I get them side by side but have the container be bang in the middle. Note I have no outer containers to #container because I need the container to be middle not an outer container to be middle.

Thanks In advance.

Ian

Comment: You can't achieve this without the outer container.

Comment: You need a parent container

Comment: hmmm, using a outer/parent container would mean that the outercontainer would be centered, meaning the #containber would be slightly off centre due to the #sidecontainer being in the same div

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this? http://jsfiddle.net/HLUYj/

```
 <div id="container">
    <div id="sidecontainer"></div>
</div>
#container {
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background: red;
    height:200px
}
  #sidecontainer {
        width:200px;
        float:left;
    background:green;
        height:200px
    }
```

Comment: This float the #sidecontainer inside the #container, I need it outside the #container

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap them both in a new div.

```
#new-container{
    width: 1160px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#container{
    width: 960px;
}

#sidecontainer{
    width: 200px;
    float: left; /* You might want to use display:inline-block instead */
}
```

Therefore, you HTML code should be:

```
<div id="new-container">
    <div id="container"></div>
    <div id="sidecontainer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Surly this would put the new #container in the middle of the page, hence the container would be slightly off centre, I need #container to be bang middle

Answer (score 0):

You can try to achieve it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/vgXn5/

But I think you should go with a parent container if your page is not fixed size. 
the reason for this is when you will resize, hte #sidecontainer will overflow the #container.

**CSS**

```
#sidecontainer {
        width:200px;
        position:absolute;
    background-color:blue;
    }
#container {
    width:300px;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:-150px;
    left:50%;
    background-color:black;
}
```